# How does one express an arbitrary number of letters for a chessboard?

Tags: notation, index-notation, chessboard

I once had the problem that I was writing about a chessboard of an arbitrary length with the usual notation of numbers and letters. I now wanted to do a little sketch of the start and ending of this infinite chessboard. For the numbers, you can name the chessboard columns $1, 2, 3, ..., n-2, n-1, n$, of course. But how would you do that with letters for the rows?

I myself came up with the idea of using the last greek letters: $a, b, c, ... \chi, \psi, \omega$. After a little research, I just found attempts that showed just the beginning of the chessboard, where they started to duplicate the letters: $a, b, c, ... z, aa, bb, cc, ... zz, aaa, bbb ...$ ([picture on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:TaikyokuShogiSente.svg)). Similar things happen of course in Microsoft Excel: $a, b, c, ... z, aa, ab, ac, ... az, ba, bb ...$. Still, these sources never show the "end" of an infinite/arbitrary length chessboard (or a similar table).

Are there any examples in literature of how this problem is handled?

Comment: just like in poetry (rhyme schemes) yea you would start notating in aa, bb, etc

Comment: A matrix notation $a_{ij}$ will do ?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Most of the times, it will do, but sometimes you just need a chessboard / Excel table numeration system like "A1" or "D3". It wouldn't always make sense to count with a variable $a$ when you actually just need its indices $i, j$ while the $a$ itself stays unused. Maybe my point here is understandable.

Comment: @user29418 That's what I already wrote in my question. Although, it doesn't solve the problem of giving an imaginary ending of this "alphanumeric numeration", like you would use $n$ for $1, 2, ..., n$ or $1..n$ for a "standard" (numeric) numeration and so on.

Comment: How about $1,...,n$ and $A_1,...,A_n$. Then you have cells $A_1 2$, $A_{183} 276$,... To me that would be a sensible generalisation of combination of letter and number.

Comment: @Jonas Still, my problem is: There appears to be some kind of semantic when using the specific letter $A$ when there actually isn't (see my comment on MauroALLEGRANZA's suggestion). It leaves the reader with the possible question like "If there is an $A$, why isn't there a $B$?". That would be my impression at least.

Comment: I now came up with another idea myself: Maybe it would be a good idea to use powers. Because, if you continue the pattern of $a, b, c, ..., z, aa, ..., zz, aaa, ..., zzz, aaaa ...$, maybe you could write something like $a, b, ..., z^m$. That would lead to a notation where you have a last chessboard tile called "$z^mn$":

$\left(\begin{matrix}
A1 & A2 & A3 & \cdots & An\\
B1 & B2 & B3 & \cdots & Bn\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
Z^m1 & Z^m2 & Z^m3 & \cdots & Z^mn
\end{matrix}\right)$

Would that contradict any mathematical notation conventions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the best thing is just to invent a notation that fits all your wishes and then explain it to the reader. You could say, for example, "We'll let $\omega$ represent the letter corresponding to the last column; for example, on a regular chessboard, $\omega$ would mean $h$, whereas on a chessboard with $n=53$, $\omega$ would mean $ba$." (if you use the Excel numbering) "Now consider the columns $a,b,\dots,\omega$ and the rows $1,2,\dots,n$"